# How do I detect ActiveDirectory Schema master from the command line in Windows Server 2003 and WS2k3R2?

Tags: active-directory

This [spectacular](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) MSDN article details how to do it in C++.  And it vaguely mentions some utilities that don't appear to be on my system at all, and gives no ideas how to do this from a regular Windows Server 2003 R2 or Windows Server 2003 domain controller.

The need to detect an active directory schema master occurs because (even though I can't figure out how this happened) I am trying to run `adprep` as a step in upgrading from 2003 to 2008R2 or 2012 server level domains, but its first command that you run (adprep /domainPrep and adprep /forestPrep) should be run on something called the "Schema Master".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From a GUI**

On a computer with the AD tools installed (ADUC, Sites & Services, etc)

1. Run `regsvr32 schmmgmt.dll` from an elevated command prompt
2. Run mmc.exe
3. In the empty console that opens add the Active Directory Schema Management snap-in.
4. Right click on the Schema icon and select Operations Master. This will show you who currently holds it and allow you to transfer it.

[image]

---

**From the command line**

`netdom query fsmo`.

`netdom.exe` is built into Windows 7 (and maybe Vista) and it part of the 2003 Resource Kit. I believe that it is also installed on 2003 Domain Controllers during dcpromo.

Comment: "I believe that it is also installed on 2003 Domain Controllers during dcpromo."
It's not on my 2003 Small Business Server (which is always a Domain Controller). Unless it just isn't in the path.